# Is there a better/more efficient way to process this JSON array?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, mysqli

I'm getting data from an API in JSON format. It's getting the resting heart rate of the user and inserting it into my database. It gets todays date as well as a couple days in the past and updates the database accordingly. The code below does work (although it's inserting a blank row for some reason). My question is, is there a better/more efficient way of writing this code?

Here is the array:

```
[activities-heart] => Array (
[0] => Array (
    [dateTime] => 2018-03-22
    [value] => Array (
        [customHeartRateZones] => Array ( )
        [heartRateZones] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [caloriesOut] => 1135.7736
                [max] => 85
                [min] => 30
                [minutes] => 814
                [name] => Out of Range
                )
            [1] => Array (
                [caloriesOut] => 1260.7179
                [max] => 119
                [min] => 85
                [minutes] => 289
                [name] => Fat Burn
                )
            [2] => Array (
                [caloriesOut] => 690.64515
                [max] => 145
                [min] => 119
                [minutes] => 90
                [name] => Cardio
                )
            [3] => Array (
                [caloriesOut] => 0
                [max] => 220
                [min] => 145
                [minutes] => 0
                [name] => Peak
                )
            )
        [restingHeartRate] => 65
        )
    )
[1] => Array (
    [dateTime] => 2018-03-23
    [value] => Array (
        [customHeartRateZones] => Array ( )
        [heartRateZones] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [caloriesOut] => 1512.00346
                [max] => 85
                [min] => 30
                [minutes] => 1113
                [name] => Out of Range
                )
            [1] => Array (
                [caloriesOut] => 1315.59604
                [max] => 119
                [min] => 85
                [minutes] => 280
                [name] => Fat Burn
                )
            [2] => Array (
                [caloriesOut] => 98.14618
                [max] => 145
                [min] => 119
                [minutes] => 13
                [name] => Cardio
                )
            [3] => Array (
                [caloriesOut] => 0
                [max] => 220
                [min] => 145
                [minutes] => 0
                [name] => Peak
                )
            )
        [restingHeartRate] => 64
        )
    )
)
```

And here is the relevant code to process it:

```
    <?php
    $obj = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveArrayIterator( json_decode( $return, TRUE ) ), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST );

    foreach ( $obj as $key => $val ) {
        $$key = $val;

        $stmt = $connection->prepare( "INSERT INTO heartrate SET `encodedid` = ?, activitydate = ?, rhr = ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rhr= ?" );
        $stmt->bind_param( 'ssii', $studentencodedid, $dateTime, $restingHeartRate, $restingHeartRate );
        $stmt->execute();

        if ( $stmt->affected_rows < 1 ) {
            header( "Location: " . $url . "/index.php?errormessage=Failed to updated the resting heart rate value." );
        exit;
        }

        $stmt->close();
    }
```

Thanks for any feedback.

Tim

Comment: That's a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ :)

Comment: This would indeed be good for Code Review, you may want to fix the code indentation though, looks like it may have got mangled when you copied it from your IDE/editor.

Comment: It is far more efficient if you combine your insert statements and execute one single query with all of the data you need to insert. However if there are only a few rows, you're not going to feel any difference. We're talking milliseconds per query. But when you're inserting thousands of rows, milliseconds turns into seconds. Also, you need to use parametrized queries or else your script is open to SQL injection. Finally, this is just personal preference, but I would throw an `Exception` instead of sending a Location header. Browsers cache redirects, so it can make debugging difficult.

Comment: Also, if you're ever sending a Location header, make sure to `exit;` or script execution will continue.

Comment: Thanks guys. @Mike, I combined my statements and used parametrized queries. I haven't used those before. The code is working, so I must have done it correctly. Still trying to figure out how to use an Exception.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @TimM Just `throw new Exception("Failed to updated the resting heart rate value.");` should work. You can then [set an Exception handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) to handle any uncaught exceptions and display a message to the user however you want, or log it to a file, email it to yourself, whatever.

Comment: Thank you @Mike.

Comment: Using the same array, I'm having trouble figuring out how to access the caloriesOut. I know I can access it using this:

$t = json_decode( $return, TRUE );
echo $t["activities-heart"][0]["value"][heartRateZones][1][caloriesOut];

But I need to figure out how to access each of the caloriesOut using the same approach I have displayed above. Any pointers would be great.